# Add suffix to page number in the index

Tags: indexing

I can get this by `\index{apple|textit}`

```
\item apple, \textit{1}
```

But i need to have index like this

> apple, 3, 4 ex., 12-13 pr.

I tried this, but without any success

```
\newcommand{\mycommand}[1]{%
  #1 ex.%
}
...
\index{apple|mycommand}
```

**EDIT:**
Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mycommand}[1]{%
  #1 ex.%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Blablabla said Nobody 

\index{apple|textit}
\pagebreak
\index{apple|mycommand}

Blablabla said Nobody 
\printindex

\end{document}
```

Resulted **ind**-file:

```
\begin{theindex}
  \providecommand*\lettergroupDefault[1]{}
  \providecommand*\lettergroup[1]{%
      \par\textbf{#1}\par
      \nopagebreak
  }

  \lettergroup{A}
  \item apple, \textit{1}

\end{theindex}
```

Comment: Does it have to use the `imakeidx`package? I know `glossaries` can do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `xindy` you can write in a new file `my.xdy` these lines:

```
(define-location-class "arabic-page-numbers"
    ("arabic-numbers") :min-range-length 1)
(define-attributes (("mycommand")))
(markup-locref :open "\mycommand{" :close "}" :attr "mycommand")
(markup-locref-list :open "\myrange{" :close "}" :sep "--" :depth 0 :class "arabic-page-numbers")
```

and run `xindy` with `-M my` option.

See [xindy manual](http://xindy.sourceforge.net/doc/manual-3.html#ss3.2) and [this thread](https://sourceforge.net/p/xindy/mailman/message/27144959/)

In the output you can get something like this:

```
\lettergroup{A}
\item apple, \myrange{\textit{1}--\mycommand{2}}
\indexspace
\lettergroup{B}
\item banana, \myrange{\mycommand{1}--\mycommand{2}}
```

And then you redefine the commands and make some kind of switcher:

```
\newcounter{printEX}
\setcounter{printEX}{1}
\newcommand{\mycommand}[1]{%
    #1\ifcase\theprintEX\relax \or{~ex.}\fi%
}
\newcommand{\myrange}[1]{%
    \setcounter{printex}{0}#1%
    \setcounter{printEX}{1}%
}
```

Comment: May be you know how to make it works with multipage indices?

Comment: I edited the post a little, added "define-attributes"

Comment: Edited once again, added range processing.